Saving a ShapeStyle to a variable in swift
In my app I have a variety of buttons. They share many qualities but vary on color. I am trying to write a class that encompasses each of there ButtonStyles making it clear the only thing that varies it their colors.
The problem is I would also like to be able to use .tint for one of them. But that is a ShapeStyle rather than a Color.
struct CommonButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    @Environment(\.isEnabled) var isEnabled: Bool
    
    @Environment(\.isFocused) var isFocused: Bool
    
    var labelColor: Color
    
    var enabledColor: some ShapeStyle
    var pressedColor: Color
    
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .font(.system(size: 14, weight: .bold))
            .padding(.horizontal, 16)
            .padding(.vertical, 10)
            .foregroundStyle(labelColor)
            .frame(maxHeight: 40)
            .background((isEnabled && configuration.isPressed) ? pressedColor : enabledColor)
            .clipShape(Capsule())
            .containerShape(Capsule())
            .opacity(isEnabled ? 1 : 0.5)
            .focusable()
    }
}

The problem here is the mismatch return types and the declaration of var enabledColor: some ShapeStyle as the compiler complains that Property declares an opaque return type, but has no initializer expression from which to infer an underlying type
Is there a way for me to get this variable to store a Color or a ShapeStyle so that I could do
CommonButtonStyle(labelColor: .black, enabledColor: .tint, pressedColor: .white)

and
CommonButtonStyle(labelColor: .black, enabledColor: .blue, pressedColor: .white)


It's not allowed. Because .background has its content as ShapeStyle or View, not both. You can make a small experiment to check it, something like:
func getSomeView() -> some View {
    if isEnabled {
        Text("Halo") //<- ❌ error here
    } else {
        Button {
        } label: {
            Text("Hello")
        }
    }
}

So, in this scenario, .background will not work at all. It cannot take two different types as its content. You must find a solution to split it, two .background separately somehow.

.background((isEnabled && configuration.isPressed) ? pressedColor : enabledColor)

Thanks to @Mojitaba with his solution.
From now on, you're able to do a if condition such as:
struct CommonButtonStyle<Background: ShapeStyle>: ButtonStyle {
    ...
    var enabledColor: Background
    var pressedColor: Color
    
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            ...
            .apply {
                if isEnabled && configuration.isPressed {
                    $0.background(pressedBg)
                } else {
                    $0.background(enableBg)
                }
            }
            ...
    }
}

var body: some View {
    Button {
    } label: {
        Text("Button 1")
    }
    .buttonStyle(CommonButtonStyle(
        labelColor: .black,
        enabledColor: LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.yellow, .purple]),
                                     startPoint: .leading,
                                     endPoint: .trailing),
        pressedColor: .white)
    )
}

Output:


Nice aproach :D

This is excellent. Now I am confused on my last step. func PrimaryButton() -> PikaButtonStyle {
return CommonButtonStyle(labelColor: .white, enabledColor: .tint, pressedColor: .green300)
}

"type any ShapeStyle cannot conform to ShapeStyle"

You're returning .tint which is a TintShapeStyle. So the concrete type must be defined such as func primaryButton() -> CommonButtonStyle<TintShapeStyle> {  .init(labelColor: .white, enabledColor: .tint, pressedColor: .green300) }

Using a ternary operator to switch the style of background doesn't work, because the types don't match.
However, you can just use background(alignment:content:) with an if-else switch instead. This modifier takes a closure, which is a ViewBuilder.
Other points:

To pass the ShapeStyle to your custom ButtonStyle, the custom style needs to be turned into a generic.

Instead of applying .clipShape(Capsule()), you could use a Capsule as the shape to be filled by the background.


struct CommonButtonStyle<S>: ButtonStyle
where S: ShapeStyle {
    @Environment(\.isEnabled) var isEnabled: Bool
    @Environment(\.isFocused) var isFocused: Bool

    var labelColor: Color
    var enabledColor: S
    var pressedColor: Color

    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .font(.system(size: 14, weight: .bold))
            .padding(.horizontal, 16)
            .padding(.vertical, 10)
            .foregroundStyle(labelColor)
            .frame(maxHeight: 40)
            .background {
                if isEnabled && configuration.isPressed {
                    Capsule().fill(pressedColor)
                } else {
                    Capsule().fill(enabledColor)
                }
            }
            .containerShape(Capsule())
            .opacity(isEnabled ? 1 : 0.5)
            .focusable()
    }
}

Your two examples now compile and work:
Button("Tinted") {}
    .buttonStyle(CommonButtonStyle(labelColor: .black, enabledColor: .tint, pressedColor: .white))
Button("Colored") {}
    .buttonStyle(CommonButtonStyle(labelColor: .black, enabledColor: .blue, pressedColor: .white))


